# Extracting the Most Phrases up to X number of Words

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an interesting algorithmic/java question that I thought I "beat" and was super simple but turns out I'm not getting the desired output:

You have a string of phrases present. For your simplicity consider them to be integer length.

String s= "I am Tom" 
will be stored in an interger array as [1,2,3] where each represents length of each word in the string.

Write a method to compute the longest subsequence such that it is less than or equal to given k value.

```
Input: 
3 //length of array 
1 //a[0] 
2 //a[1] 
3 //a[2] 
4 // value of k 

Output: 
2 

Input: 
4 //length of array 
3 
1 
2 
1 
4 //value of k 

Output: 
3
```

My initial thought is okay this is super easy, I'm going to sort this array (doesn't state that you couldn't) and theoretically all the smallest numbers should be first. Run through the array index by index adding them up until `<= k` is no longer true. Then I ran it against given tests, it passes the first 2 and fails on the 3rd. Here's my code for sorting and adding:

```
// k is the number we want to sum the phrases up to
// a is the length of a phrase
// Need to add phrases together to get the most phrases less than or equal to k
// Algorithm: Probably want to sort the list then add from the front until > k
static int maxLength(int[] a, int k) {
    int sum = 0;
    int numPhrases = 0;

    Arrays.sort(a);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if((sum + a[i]) <= k) {
            sum += a[i];
            numPhrases++;
        }

    }

    return numPhrases;
}
```

We were given the following uneditable code (along with the imports):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String fileName = System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        int res;

        int _a_size = 0;
        _a_size = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
        int[] _a = new int[_a_size];
        int _a_item;
        for(int _a_i = 0; _a_i < _a_size; _a_i++) {
            _a_item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
            _a[_a_i] = _a_item;
        }

        int _k;
        _k = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());

        res = maxLength(_a, _k);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(res));
        bw.newLine();

        bw.close();
}
```

Which essentially did all the work and just gives you the number k (Words that you can add up to) and the array of numbers you're adding.

It broke on the following test:

```
Input:
61
74    
659    
931    
273
545
879
924
710   
441   
166   
493  
43   
988   
504   
328  
730   
841  
613   
304  
170 
710  
158 
561  
934  
100 
279  
817 
336
98 
827 
513
268
811
634
980
150
580
822
968
673
394
337
486
746
229
92
195
358
2
154
709
945
669
491
125
197
531
904
723
667
550
22337
```

With an expected output of `46`

My program gives the output of `51` here.

Thanks for the help, I'm very confused as to why this isn't correct.

Comment: This sounds like the knapsack problem. For the small number of inputs you show, there is an absolute solution. In general, you will have to use heuristics, and the greedy algorithm is not optimal by any means.

Comment: Given that you are dealing with numbers, what does "I am Tom" have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: I think you need to break the loop when this condition `(sum + a[i]) <= k` is false.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique It doesn't add the numbers when it's false, thus not incrementing numPhrases+=

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's how you get the num of characters/words. Rather, to make the problem simpler they give you numbers of characters per word instead of the string to make it easier to solve.

Comment: According to your question, the condition must be `lesser than k` and you're comparing `lesser or equals than k`.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique It's a typo, it's <= let me adjust

Comment: Ah right! Let's continue :-)

Comment: @NikkiNelson. I meant that the whole section about "I am Tom" confuses the issue if it is not part of the actual input. It may be advisable to remove it.

Comment: Specifically, do you include the spaces between each word in the desired subsequence length?

Comment: @MadPhysicist From my understanding, which is I guess all we can base off of since the 3rd input/output errored out with that specific code each number is representing a number of characters since I doubt there's words > 100/200+ characters. That being said, my thought is we're just adding each element to get the largest group of words/characters. Obviously it's not that simple.

Comment: I hard coded the answer to number 3 and it ran the code against 7 hidden input/outputs all being wrong. So there must be something illogical about sorting and adding the smallest number which is where I'm beyond confused.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Space-separated is the answer to your question

Comment: Can you paste the exact problem's statement?  There is no way to return 46 and sum > k

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Here's Twitters' interation of the full question: http://prntscr.com/hgianb

Answer (score 0):

After reading the statement,

**Solution found at :** http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-subarray-sum-elements-atmost-k/

```
static int maxLength(int[] arr, int k) {
    int sum = 0;
    int cnt = 0, maxcnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // If adding current element doesn't
        // cross limit add it to current window
        if ((sum + arr[i]) <= k) {
            sum += arr[i];
            cnt++;
        }

        // Else, remove first element of current
        // window.
        else if (sum != 0) {
            sum = sum - arr[i - cnt] + arr[i];
        }

        // keep track of max length.
        maxcnt = Math.max(cnt, maxcnt);
    }
    return maxcnt;
}
```

An efficient approach is to use sliding window technique.

- Traverse the array and check if on adding the current element its sum is less than or equal to k.
- If it’s less than k then add it to sum and increase the count.
- Else
  Remove the first element of subarray and decrease the count.
  Again check if on adding the current element its sum is less than or equal to k.
  If it’s less than k then add it to sum and increase the count.
- Keep track of Maximum count.

This is the right solution.

**Hope this helps!**